# Searching through nested data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, search, nested

I cant figure out what is wrong with this search function/s? I want to be able to search for the word bird or snake. Also it would be nice to ignor any object that dont have that text in them. I am confused as this person never uses her "animals" object array and I never see getEachItem actually called?

[example tutorial](https://dev.to/alisabaj/searching-through-a-nested-object-using-recursion-regular-expressions-and-sets-bm7)

```
const SlideData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Slide 0",
    layout: "standard",
    content: [
      {
        id: 1,
        type: "paragraph",
        text: "this has the word cat."
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        type: "space",
        height: "1em"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        type: "paragraph",
        text: "this has the word snake."
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Slide 1",
    layout: "standard",
    content: [
      {
        id: 1,
        type: "paragraph",
        text: "This has the word bird."
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        type: "space",
        height: "1em"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        type: "paragraph",
        text: "This has the word bear."
      }
    ],
  }
];
export default SlideData;
```

```
import SlideData from "./SlideData";

const SearchResults = () => {
  const searchTerm = "bird";
  let result = [];

  function getEachItem(object) {
    object.forEach((item) => {
      searchItem(item);
    });
    let uniqueResults = [...new Set(result)];
    return uniqueResults.length;
  }
  function searchItem(item) {
    SlideData.forEach((key) => {
      if (typeof item[key] === "object") {
        searchItem(item[key]);
      }
      if (typeof item[key] === "string") {
        let searchAsRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "gi");
        if (item[key].match(searchAsRegEx)) {
          result.push(item.id);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Results</h1>
      <p>{result}</p>
      <button type="submit" onClick={searchItem}>
        Search
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SearchResults;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing a recursive call to searchItem, but you never specify a return condition to pop the call stack and return the flow of control back to the original caller

```
function searchItem(item) {
    SlideData.forEach((key) => {
      if (typeof item[key] === "object") {
        /** return result of recursive call **/
        return searchItem(item[key]);
      }
      if (typeof item[key] === "string") {
        let searchAsRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "gi");
        if (item[key].match(searchAsRegEx)) {
          result.push(item.id);
        }
      }
      /** return and pop call stack
       * since you pushed an item to the result array
       **/
      return;
    });
  }
```

It would be better to have the searchItem function do all of the iterating and return an array result instead of recursively trying to push items onto a global array. You're mixing scopes with the way you're doing it now

Answer (score 0):

Tutorials are often low effort affairs. The author of this one seems to be sharing a partial implementation of something they wrote for a different project, and is posting it to try to get feedback. They aren't writing an app with a complete search implementation.

In your case, to make the search work for terms other than "bird", you'll have to make `searchTerm` an argument that is passed into the function. You'll also have to set up the form and display areas to put the results in.

To reiterate, the tutorial is only giving you part of a complete app. You'll have to set up the rest yourself.